# Override a view in eclipse 4 application

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am a software that used to run on eclipse 3 platform. Now post upgrade the eclipse platform has changed to  rcp4. Now there was a view which we had overridden and could see but now after the upgrade the view cannot be overridden and we see the view which is not overridden. Some changes that have occurred in 4 that could affect the same.

The part in the xml where we try to override

```
    <view category="org.eclipse.ui"
         allowMultiple="true"
        class="com.teamcenter.rac.siemens.views.MyView"
        icon="platform:/plugin/com.teamcenter.rac.ui/icons_16/referencers_16.png"
        id="com.teamcenter.rac.ui.views.SummaryView" name="%summary.VIEW">
    </view>
    <!--The value against the id is something I am overriding-->
```

Comment: This is very unclear. You need to explain in much more detail what you were doing and what doesn't work anymore.

Comment: We have an Out of the box Summary view which is there in the software . Now customizing the view for the client we used to override it.

Comment: We have the view I'd and would just replace the class againts the id of the view that was there.

Comment: Replace how? [edit] your question and show us **exactly** what you were doing. However I don't think this was ever supported.

Comment: I have added the part that we used t override against the ID

Comment: I don't think this was ever supported, how would Eclipse know which view was the 'correct' one? It may just have been luck that it worked in Eclipse 3.

Comment: In my view it is not possible as Teamcenter is written in Eclipse 3 and you can customize  RAC plugin to E4.

Comment: With Teamcneter 11 and prior versions we could override as above and you mentioned it was TC11. Now we upgraded to TC12 and that has E4. On TC12 platform it is not working.